# JQuery Clone - Triggering the same event on both elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

If I clone an element with events `.clone(true)` and append it within the same page. Can I trigger the same 'live' click event on both.

For example, if I build my own select menu using 'ul' and 'li' elements and add a 'live' click' event on it's class e.g. '.selectOption'. Can I make the original element change when the cloned one does?

I don't really have a code example, but I have run into trouble with this before. The original stays the same if you select one of the options. I have tried triggering a click on the original, but that does not work either.

I don't understand why the event will not make both change. It is pointing to both because they have the same class and structure.

Comment: It would be truly helpful if you could dig up some code... It's hard to say what's wrong without it.

Comment: Did you .clone(true) ?

Comment: jquery's [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (see section 'Direct and Delegated Events') addresses your needs. attach your event handler to any common ancestor of the original node and each of its potential clones. choose a suitable selector covering those clones when calling `.on`. note that `.live` is deprecated as of v1.7 and has been removed in 1.9.

Comment: I don't think delegate does the trick either as live is basically the same. I will try dig up some code. Yes dschazam, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.delegate()` or `.live()`, you should try using `.on()` instead. Let's say you are cloning the element with the class name **item**, then you can use the following code to bind an event, say, a click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    // Do magic here that changes things in both the original item and its cloned counterpart
});
```

How `.on()` works is that it listens for events to bubble up the DOM tree until it reaches your selected element of interest, and in this case, `document`. The caveat is that the element you are listening on event bubbling has to be present in the DOM when jQuery is executed, and `document` is the safest way to do it. Of course you can also use `.on()` on other static elements that are present in the DOM, such as `<body>`.

---

The OP has furnished with additional information. It seems that OP wants the changes done to one element to propagate to its cloned counterpart, and not simply binding the same handlers to the cloned elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selectMenu = $('.selectMenu');
    $selectMenu.on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(this).css('background','red');
    });

    $selectMenu.clone(true).appendTo('body');
});
```

In this case, I would advocate the use of indexes (with `.index()`) for DOM transversal in the context of the element's parent.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $selectMenu = $('.selectMenu');
    $selectMenu.on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(".selectMenu").find('li:eq('+$(this).index()+')').css('background','red');
    });

    $selectMenu.clone(true).appendTo('body');
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4Jxv2/2/

Also, some possible improvements:

- Add/remove classes instead of directly manipulating inline CSS of the element
- Use `.on()` so that you can bind events that are not originally bound to the element before cloning.

See revised function below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Clone first, worry about binding events later
    $('.selectMenu').clone(true).appendTo('body');

    // Bind events
    $(document).on('click', '.selectMenu li', function() {
        $('.selectMenu')
        .find('li:eq('+$(this).index()+')')
            .addClass('highlighted');
    });

});
```

where the class `.highlighted` can be used to declare the background color :) See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4Jxv2/3/

Comment: I did, and what is your issue?

Comment: Hey, I have used 'on'. This slightly improves the functionality. It will make the original change if I select a new option from the cloned one. It will not make both change however. It only does this if I use .clone() and not pass in true as well.

Comment: @Terry the issue is not about using on or live !! it is known As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated , the issue is triggering multiple actions on cloned elements , so no , this is not the correct answer for that , i would answer this and share my code , if there was a code in question .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Jxv2/1/

Take a look at this simple example. I want the original 'li' to turn red when the clone 'li' is clicked. I want both to trigger on that one click.

Comment: @Paddy Thanks! I just updated my answer. You can also see the fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4Jxv2/2/

Comment: This answered my question excellently. I am however having trouble in another way. What if an event was created on the original first and then I created a new one?

If I used .clone(true) it would only clone the first event. My new clone would not trigger on my new click event. Would I have to .off() on the first?

Comment: Then you will have to use the `.on()` method I mentioned in my answer. `.clone(true)` will only copy events that *have already been bound* when the method was called. I would also recommend adding classes instead of directly manipulating CSS :)

Comment: Could you explain a little more because I did use on for both.
Haha, I would normally. That was just in the example :)

Comment: You used `.on()`, but on which element are you listening it on? You cannot listen to `.selectMenu` because the other instances are dynamically added. Also, read my updated answer.

Comment: Please refrain from calling people “downvote-happy prick”s in the future.

Comment: This does not appear to work. It ignores the new click event. Imagine there are two click events on the page. One was created on the selectMenu before it was cloned. Next, the select menu was cloned and a new event was setup. If you pass clone(true), the 2nd event is never triggered, only the first.

Comment: That's why you need to use `$(document).on('click',...)` because the second event is added **after** the cloning has been performed.

Comment: I tried it with the document, but it still only detected the first.

Comment: Diagnosis of your problem is very hard unless you can provide us a minimal replica of your issue.